# Find XML attribute using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

Need to find all the Job **Name** where the **Valid** attribute of **job** node is **true** and the **JobLocation** is NOT **Country=England** using select -xml in powershell

```
<Employee>
  <job id = "123" Name = "Teacher" Valid ="True">
    <jobdetails>
      <JobLocation location="City=London,Country=England" JobType="Permanent"/>
    </jobdetails>
  </job>
  <job id = "356" Name = "Doctor" Valid ="True">
    <jobdetails>
      <JobLocation location="City=Tokyo,Country=Japan" JobType="Permanent"/>
    </jobdetails>
  </job>
  <job id = "987" Name = "Banker" Valid ="True">
    <jobdetails>
      <JobLocation location="City=Manchester,Country=England" JobType="Permanent"/>
    </jobdetails>
  </job>
</Employee>
```

Xml paths i have tried out

```
$xml ='//Employee/job[@Valid="True"]/jobdetails*[@*[contains(.,!"Country=England")]]/job/@Id'



$xml ='//Employee/job[@Valid="True"]/jobdetails*[@*[contains(.JobLocation,!"Country=England")]]/job/@Id'
```

Comment: Do you have any code you're working with? This isn't a website to request someone to write everything for you.

Comment: This doesn't look valid.  This entity doesn't appear to have a name: `<JobLocation="City=London,Country=England" JobType="Permanent"/>`  I guess it's meant to be 'JobLocation', but it's being used like an attribute.

Comment: @boxdog corrected the xml

Comment: `.../job[...]/job/...` would match a `<job>` node inside another `<job>` node. Also, `Id` != `id`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers how to go back to parent node and how to skip Country=England. Any lead please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XPath filter expression (the text in square brackets) can consist of multiple clauses. To filter by a child node's value or attribute simply include the relative path to the child node or attribute as a second clause in the filter expression and connect the clauses with the appropriate logical operator. To filter by an attribute not containing a particular substring use the `not()` and `contains()` functions.

```xml
//Employee/job[@Valid="True" and jobdetails/JobLocation[not(contains(@location, "Country=England"))]]/@id
```

Answer (score 2):

The non-xpath way:

```
[Xml]$xml = Get-Content employee.xml
$xml.employee.job | 
  Where { $_.valid -And 
    $_.jobdetails.joblocation.location -Notmatch 'england' } | 
  Select valid, @{n='Location';e={$_.jobdetails.joblocation.location}}


Valid Location
----- --------
True  City=Tokyo,Country=Japan
```